# How would I run a script every 30 seconds?

Tags: c#, timer

How would I have my ftp script run every 10 or 30 seconds?

ftp script:

```
FtpWebRequest makedir = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/" + System.Environment.MachineName + "___" + System.Environment.UserName + @"/");
makedir.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
makedir.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usr", @"passwd");
FtpWebResponse makedirStream = (FtpWebResponse)makedir.GetResponse();
makedirStream.Close();
```

I was reading about using sleep on a thread and also about using a timer.. but I cant figure out how to use either.. The thing is that it also needs to rerun every 30 seconds not just once.

Comment: Is this WinForms? WebForms? Console? WPF? Something else?  Does anything else need to be running at the same time?

Comment: The answer below is good. However think carefully about your goals here. It's not common to want to do such a thing. Is it to check the FTP server is running? A form of error handling if you can't connect to the server? There may be better ways.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Its a console program And possibly an upload.. im sure i can figure that out from what is below..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your code in a method, for example named `RunFtp()` & then use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer)
like this:

```
var t = new System.Threading.Timer(
    callback: o => RunFtp(), 
    state: null, 
    dueTime: 0,      // run now
    period: 30000);  // milliseconds
```

There are many different types of timer in .NET, see the green panel in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-8.0#remarks) in the link above for a list.

Or use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) to schedule and run the application repeatedly.

Or use [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) like this...

```
while (true)
{
    RunFtp();
    System.Threading.Task.Delay(30000).Wait();
}
```

...to make your code to pause for 30 seconds between executions, but you also need to add the execution time of your code each time, so that it will start running every 30 seconds accurately.

You may also want to consider running this with async/await if you want to avoid blocking.

Comment: Thanks! If i have any issues.. ill leave a comment letting you know.

Comment: No probs, will be offline soon for zeds, but back early morning.